# When to quantify ignored pattern match in the C sscanf function

Tags: c++, c, portability, scanf, cppcheck

[Cppcheck 1.67](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) raised a portability issue in my source code at this line:

```
sscanf(s, "%d%*[,;.]%d", &f, &a);
```

This is the message I got from it:

> scanf without field width limits can crash with huge input data on some versions of libc.

The original intention of the format string was to accept one of three possible limiter chars between two integers, and today - thanks to Cppcheck<sup>[1]</sup> - I see that `%*[,;.]` accepts even strings of limiter chars. However I doubt that my format string may cause a crash, because the unlimited part is ignored.

**Is there possibly an issue with a buffer overrun?** <sup>...maybe behind the scenes?</sup>

---

<sup>[1]</sup>
How to get lost between farsightedness and blindness:

I tried to fix it by `%1*[,;.]` (after [some API doc](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/comp/unix/package/rtems/doc/html/libc/libc.info.scanf.html)), but Cppcheck insisted in the issue, so I also tried `%*1[,;.]` with the same "success". Seems that I have to suppress it for now...

Comment: So, you have a working correct format, and you change it to something else (probably not correct?) to suppress a false positive, without success? Looks more like a job for "inline-suppressions": Search it here http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/manual.pdf

Comment: the message pointed out is meaningless because `%*[,;.]` do not use the buffer .

Comment: @Deduplicator No, I tried to improve the pattern to my *actual* needs Cppcheck helped to detect.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY true, but in my case there was a tiny problem...

Comment: If you really only want to match exactly one of those characters exactly once, you could just assign. (And submit a bug-report against your version of cppcheck)

Comment: @Deduplicator the `scanf` API doc also allows for skipping...

Comment: Buffer overrun does not.

Comment: @Wolf: Yes, that's a workaround. I suggested submitting a bug-report above, right?

Comment: @Deduplicator. Yes, that's a bug in Cppcheck. But I'll use an inline suppression and the correct format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulations on finding a bug in Cppcheck 1.67 (the current version).

You have basically three workarounds:

1. Just ignore the false positive.
2. Rework your format (assign that field, possible as you only want to match one character).

   ```
   char tmp;
   if(3 != sscanf(s, "%d %c%d", &f, &tmp, &a) || tmp!=',' && tmp!=';' && tmp!= '.')
       goto error;
   ```
3. Suppress the warning directly (preferably inline-suppressions):

   ```
   //cppcheck-suppress invalidscanf_libc
   if(2 != sscanf(s, "%d%1*[,;.]%d", &f, &a))
       goto error;
   ```

Don't forget to report the error, as "defect / false positive", so you can retire and forget that workaround as fast as possible.

Comment: Again, please rethink the separator handling in #2. As I found out, `"%d%c%d"` absolutely does the job, because it's a separator (which cannot be a digit).

Comment: But there might be white-space. Unless you say there cannot be, and that possibility was implicit in the original `scanf`.

Comment: (in the original, there was no whitespace) Sorry, the title falsely stated that the question would be about the `scanf` function, the text did not have this error.

Answer (score 1):

> When to quantify ignored pattern match in the C sscanf function?

Probably it's a good idea to always quantify (see below), but over-quantification may also distract from your intentions. In the above case, where *a single separator char* has to be skipped, the quantification would definitely be useful.

> Is there possibly an issue with a buffer overrun? ...maybe behind the scenes?

There will be no crashes caused by *your code*. As to deal with the "behind the scenes" question, I experimented with large input strings. In the C library I tested, there was no internal buffer overflow. I tried the C lib that's shipped with Borland C++ 5.6.4 and found that **I could not trigger a buffer overrun** with large inputs (more than 400 million chars).

Surprisingly, **Cppcheck was not totally wrong** - there is a portability issue, but a different one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sstream>

int traced_sscanf_set(const int count, const bool limited)
{
    const char sep = '.';
    printf("\n");
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "123" << std::string(count, sep) << "456";
    std::string s = ss.str();
    printf("string of size %d with %d '%c's in it\n", s.size(), count, sep);
    std::stringstream fs;
    fs << "%d%";
    if (limited) {
        fs << count;
    }
    fs << "*["<< sep << "]%d";
    std::string fmt = fs.str();
    printf("fmt: \"%s\"\n", fmt.c_str());
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    const sscanfResult = sscanf(s.c_str(), fmt.c_str(), &a, &b);
    printf("sscanfResult=%d, a=%d, b=%d\n", sscanfResult, a, b);
    return sscanfResult;
}

void test_sscanf()
{
    assert(traced_sscanf_set(0x7fff, true)==2);
    assert(traced_sscanf_set(0x7fff, false)==2);
    assert(traced_sscanf_set(0x8000, true)==2);
    assert(traced_sscanf_set(0x8000, false)==1);
}
```

The library I checked, internally limits the input consumed (and skipped) to 32767 (2<sup>15</sup>-1) chars, if there is no explicitly specified limit in the format parameter.

For those who are interested, here is the trace output:

```
string of size 32773 with 32767 '.'s in it
fmt: "%d%32767*[.]%d"
sscanfResult=2, a=123, b=456

string of size 32773 with 32767 '.'s in it
fmt: "%d%*[.]%d"
sscanfResult=2, a=123, b=456

string of size 32774 with 32768 '.'s in it
fmt: "%d%32768*[.]%d"
sscanfResult=2, a=123, b=456

string of size 32774 with 32768 '.'s in it
fmt: "%d%*[.]%d"
sscanfResult=1, a=123, b=0
```